# Running unit tests in plone on third-party eggs

Tags: python, unit-testing, plone, zope, test-runner

I'm trying to work with one of the eggs in Plone (collective.z3cform.wizard). I'm following doctests while reading documentation and at this point would like to write tests for my own code.

The problem is that while I'm following test examples they differ from what I'm getting by running my tests. I would like to run tests on that third-party egg before looking for other solutions,  the thing is -- I don't know how.

In Plone 3 it was possible to specify third-party tests through `./bin/instance test`, when I'm trying to just run `./bin/test` in Plone 4, I end up running only my development tests. So far I've tried using --module and --package options but all I seem to get is ImportErrors.

UPDATE: I'm justing buildout and here's a relevant part of it

```
[test]
recipe = zc.recipe.testrunner
defaults = ['--auto-color', '--auto-progress']
eggs =
      ... my development eggs...
```

Comment: The `test` part in your buildout doesn't have an `eggs` entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bin/test` command is created by a buildout part, usually using the `zc.recipe.testrunner` or `collective.xmltestreport` recipes. Those recipes support an `eggs` entry to configure what eggs are available to it.

If you installed Plone with the unified installer, then the `[test]` part is set up to include the `test-packages` entry from the `[buildout]` section, so in your `development.cfg` you can add eggs to that entry as well to ensure the eggs you want to test are included.

To run all the tests for one package, use the `-s` option to `bin/test`:

```
bin/test -s collective.z3cform.wizard
```

Comment: I guess I was expecting tests, but when I looked at the code it was doctests, so the following line seems to justified:      
Total: 0 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors in 0.000 seconds. Although when I added a false assertion to one of the tests, nothing happened.